# importing binary data into Python and then exporting to Excel

Tags: python, excel

I would like to upload a large number of binary values from a file (a .phys file) into Python and then export these values into Excel for graphing purposes. Excel only supports ~32,000 rows at a time, but I have up to 3mil values in some cases. I am able to upload the data set into Python using

f = open("c:\DR005289_F00001.PHYS", "rb")

How do I then export this file to Excel in a format which Excel can support? For example, how could I break up the data into columns? I don't care how many values are in each column, it can be an arbitrary break depending on what Excel can support.

Comment: You could output to a csv file, which excel supports. Please give us some more code and information about the data if you want further help.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.python-excel.org/) has served me well. Use xlwt to Put all the data into the file.

I would create a list of lists to break the data into columns. Write each list (pick a length, 10k?) to the excel file.